# How to make the spritenode's velocity work the same when making a universal app in sprite kit

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, universal

When I am making an universal game, I apply an impulse on a subject. It works very well in iphone simulator. But when it comes to ipad simulator, the impulse is way too small. Then I replace applying impulse with setting velocity directly. It works a little better but not enough. Can anyone tell me why it works differently?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Set constant mass values for each physicsBody.

Comment: @akashg I tried setting the mass. _player.physicsbody.mass = 1; but it didn't help. Is there any problem?

Comment: Can you describe how it didnt help?

Comment: @akashg I am developing a player jumping against the gravity. I set         self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, - 4.5);

Comment: @akashg and set        _player.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(200, 330);  But it works differently in ipad and iphone. In ipad simulator, it works much more weaker, which means the player in ipad is very slow. While in iphont simulator, the player can jump much higher